# Symfony 2 custom DQL request inside an array field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I'm trying to make a custom request in my repository with a WHERE clause inside an array field. I tried something like that, not working, but can better show my problem :

```
$qb ->andWhere( "p.addresses[:index] = :address" )
    ->setParameter( "index" , $p_idLang )
    ->setParameter( "address" , $p_address );
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? could you elaborate?

Comment: I'm trying to test a value inside the persisted array in my where clause : @ORM\Column(name="addresses", type="array", nullable=true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracted from the [documentation](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/types.html#array-types) about array type:

> Maps and converts array data based on PHP serialization. If you need
>   to store an exact representation of your array data, you should
>   consider using this type as it uses serialization to represent an
>   exact copy of your array as string in the database. Values retrieved
>   from the database are always converted to PHP’s array type using
>   deserialization or null if no data is present.

Your query doesn't make sense. You have a few options though:

1. Retrieve `p.adresses` and check using php if `p.adresses[$index] = $address`
2. Try something much less reliable but that could work:

`$val_length = strlen($p_address);
$qb ->andWhere( "p.addresses LIKE :indexAddress" )
     ->setParameter( "indexAddress" , "%i:$p_idLang;s:$val_length:$p_address%" );`

3. Create a new entity and a relation oneToMany between this entity and the new one.

I'd definetely try option 3. Option 1 isn't an option if the array is big or will become big in the future. I wouldn't go for option 2, but as an experiment could be worth trying.

Comment: Thanks, the second solution is working fine, this array will never be really big. But int the further i'll probably implement the third solution ! Thanks